# How to use RemoteWebDriver to launch Microsoft Edge in IE mode with IEDriver?

Tags: selenium, facebook-php-webdriver

Q: Is possible to use RemoteWebDriver to launch Microsoft Edge in IE mode with IEDriver?

I'm using php-webdriver-1.12 + phpunit-5 + selenium-server-4.1.2.jar + IEDriverServer_Win32_4.0.0 , is right?

Currently im using ↓ to launch IE:

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities::internetExplorer();
$this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $ieCapabilities);
```

Is there any method to set InternetExplorerOptions ?

```
//$ieCapabilities->setCapability('_ie.edgechromium_', true);
//$ieCapabilities->setCapability('_ie.edgepath_', "the path of msedge.exe");
```